# Xcode Downloading audio working fine in Simulator but fails in TestFlight, doesn't save to iPhone device

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, download, crash-reports

I'm basically trying to save an audio file to an iPhone device, specifically in the Files app.

This is the code I'm using which works in the iOS Simulator:

```
if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3") {

    // then lets create your document folder url
    let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    // lets create your destination file url
    let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
    print(destinationUrl)

    // to check if it exists before downloading it
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
        print("The file already exists at path", destinationUrl)

        // if the file doesn't exist
    } else {

        // you can use NSURLSession.sharedSession to download the data asynchronously
        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl) { location, response, error in
            guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
            do {
                // after downloading your file you need to move it to your destination url
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
                print("File moved to documents folder", destinationUrl)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

this is the result in the simulator:

```
2022-04-08 15:48:17.605964+0200 TunnelPlay[3977:122650] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics

File moved to documents folder file:///Users/panashemuzamhindo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A7F7DD88-1E0C-45CD-9783-F46E6644F98C/data/Containers/Data/Application/EDE8B3CC-C290-4369-8B88-4AE1717B9DB8/Documents/1645329769Sengkhathele(featit.caramel).mp3
```

**Main Problem**: When I try run this section in TestFlight, the app runs the save process but theres nothing in Files, maybe I'm looking for it in the wrong location? or I need some permissions?

Desired Outcome: I want to see the downloaded MP3 in the iPhone Files app.

And I did try to change the scheme to Release instead of Debug, but it still doesn't save the file.

Comment: Crash reason message?  Crashed thread stack trace?

Comment: @PhillipMills Ok Now its no crashing, Im not sure why app runs smooth, The app just runs the script but when I check files theres nothing

Comment: @PhillipMills maybe Im looking for it in the wrong location??? or I need permissions??, Because since there no crash now, theres no Crashed thread stack trace

Comment: @PhillipMills figured it out If you want to be able to access the files in the iOS Files app, make sure to also enable LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace (in addition to enabling UIFileSharingEnabled).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access the files in the iOS Files app, make sure to also enable [`LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lssupportsopeningdocumentsinplace) (in addition to enabling [`UIFileSharingEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uifilesharingenabled))

> **LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace**
> A Boolean value indicating whether the app may open the original document from a file provider, rather than a copy of the document.

> **UIFileSharingEnabled**
> A Boolean value indicating whether the app shares files.